# Where is ORM::factory('foo') set?

Tags: php, orm, kohana

From http://dev.morgan.ly/kohana/v3.3/index.php/guide/orm-rest/basics:

```
// Use factory pattern
$member = ORM::factory('member');

// Simply create new object
$member = new Model_Member;
```

Where do people set `ORM::factory('member')` so that they can access `Model_Member` through passing `member` to `ORM::factory`?

Comment: You should read this first https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to 'set' a configuration anywhere. The only thing required is that the `Model_Member` class is in place where the class auto-loader can find it. This typically means that it should be within a module's `classes` folder, then add directories for any underscores in the class's name. For example, Some_Long_Class_Name could be found by the auto-loader in `APP_PATH.'/classes/some/long/class/name.php'`

or in your case: `APP_PATH.'/classes/model/member.php'` (Kohana <= v3.2)

In Kohana v3.3+ the folder and file names must match exactly the letter case in the class defintion: `Model_Member` => `APP_PATH.'/classes/Model/Member.php'`